# Run time polymorphism using Spring IOC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies, inversion-of-control

i have this specific question regarding spring IOC . I want to achieve runtime polymorphism using spring .

I am able to achieve the same using if else , however i would like a know a proper spring-way of doing it .

Requirement :

I have interface MyInterface .

ImplA & ImplB implements MyInterface .

I have a service which sends "A" or "B" . Based on the request-param i want to inject ImplA or ImplB in my controller  .

Please suggest what will be the best way to implement the same in spring using dependency injection

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring annotation base configuration try it:

```
  @Bean(name = "aImpl")
  public MyInterface a() {
    return new AImpl();
  }

  @Bean(name = "bImpl")
  public MyInterface b() {
    return new BImpl();
  }
```

To get the properly instance of interface clarify bean name with `@Qualifier`

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("a")
    MyInterface aImpl;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("b")
    MyInterface bImpl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Couple of ideas from my point of view:

1. Use Factory pattern to return the bean you want based on the param value.
2. Put both the beans in map and using param values as key. When you need the bean get it from the map.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `applicationContext.getBean("beanName")` inside your controller method. [Here](https://brunozambiazi.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/getting-spring-beans-programmatically/) is an example program. You can get the right impl this way based on your condition.

Comment: As I understand OP wants to get rid of conditions.

Comment: applicationContext.getBean("beanName") is working and i am able to get the required bean

Comment: You are ok with conditions?

Comment: Yes based on spring name we have given by passing the value it picks up correct bean.Bean instantation happens as start and injection happens at invocation

Comment: All conditions are getting satisfied I have Used qualifier so based on string passed from url respective bean will be picked up